# Jquery ajax send json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

**Javascript:**

```
function add_content(count)
{
    var result = {};
    var row = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         result['img_src'] = $("#img_" + i).attr('src');
         result['desc'] = $("#desc_" + i).val();
         row.push(result);
    }
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax-functions.php",
            data: {json_data: JSON.stringify(row)},
            type: 'post',
            success: function (output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        })
}
```

**Php:**

```
$img_desc = json_decode($_POST['json_data'],TRUE);
$count = count($img_desc);
echo 'count:'.$count;
print_r($img_desc);
```

I want to send json to from JS to PHP. This above code works well, but it send the **last data of the for loop is set in all the objects**.
How to fix it? Is this right way?

Thanks.

Comment: use foreach https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Push a new object on each round of the loop into to the array

```
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        row.push({
            "img_src": $("#img_" + i).attr('src'),
            "desc": $("#desc_" + i).val()
        });
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au2rucs9/)

Answer (score 1):

Move `result` declaration inside `for`:

```
var row = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
        var result = {};
        result['img_src'] = $("#img_" + i).attr('src');
        result['desc'] = $("#desc_" + i).val();
        row.push(result);
}
```

**or** it can be done more elegantly:

```
var row = new Array();
var result;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    result = row[ row.push({}) - 1 ];
    result['img_src'] = $("#img_" + i).attr('src');
    result['desc'] = $("#desc_" + i).val();
}
```

Comment: but i think it's not the good practice just only because it will object called result every time created and re initialized just think if he is having more then 1000 data then.?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `keys` of `result array` also dynamic

Since you are not making it dynmamic, its getting over ridden in the next loop

**EDIT:**

```
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
           var result = {};
            result['img_src'] = $("#img_" + i).attr('src');
            result['desc'] = $("#desc_" + i).val();
            row.push(result);

    }
```

Comment: Yes. but if i want same key and array like,
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [img_src] => img source 1
            [desc] => desc 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [img_src] => img source 2
            [desc] => desc 2
        )
)

Comment: Then you can declare the array inside the loop